# Render and pass/specify dynamic field in JSX

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I have a field object created at runtime (via API call) as below

```js
field: {
  "firstNameField-0":
    {
      id: 'firstNameField',
      mandatory: true,
      value: 'First Name 1'
    }
  }
```

The index (i.e. `0`) above is dynamic, but at a time, only one value is possible for the index  and I have this value in a state variable "index". So, basically the field names are of the format `firstNameField-${index}`

I want to pass this field object/configuration to my JSX. So, looking at something like

```
{
  field.firstNameField &&
    <MyField key={field.firstNameField.id} field={field.firstNameField} />
}
```

Is it possible to specify and render with this dynamic index in the JSX itself ?

I was trying something like below, but it is throwing syntax error;

```
<MyField key={field.[`firstNameField-${index}`].id} field={field.[`firstNameField-${index}`]}  />
```

---

UPDATED

Is there a shorthand way of writing this JSX, since it is quite verbose and repetitive ?

```
{
  myContactObj.gridItems &&
  myContactObj.gridItems[index] && 
  myContactObj.gridItems[index].fields[0] && 
  myContactObj.gridItems[index].fields[0][`firstNameField-${index}`] &&
  <MyField key={myContactObj.gridItems[index].fields[0][`firstNameField-${index}`].id} field={myContactObj.gridItems[index].fields[0][`firstNameField-${index}`]} index={index}  />
}
```

Comment: No dots in bracket notation: `<MyField key={field[\`firstNameField-${index}\`].id} field={field[\`firstNameField-${index}\`]}  />`

Answer (score 2):

Don't use dots in bracket notation.

```
<MyField key={field[`firstNameField-${index}`].id} field={field[`firstNameField-${index}`]}  />
```

To shorten nested property checks, you can use [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining).

```js
myContactObj?.gridItems?.[index]?.fields?.[0]?.[`firstNameField-${index}`]
    && <MyField ... />
```

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the dot before the brackets:

```js
const fieldValue = field[`firstNameField-${index}`];
<MyField key={fieldValue.id} field={fieldValue}  />
```

About the 2nd question, you could simplify your JSX to something like this:

```js
const fieldValue = myContactObj.gridItems?.[index].fields?.[0]?.[`firstNameField-${index}`];

// ...

{
  fieldValue &&
    <MyField key={fieldValue.id} field={fieldValue} index={index}  />
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot...This works perfectly...Final question which I have updated in the original question about shorthand syntax...Could you please see if it is possible to do that ?

Comment: Sure. Again, I would save the value in a new variable to make it more readable